# I added a Model version of my .xcdatamodeld and now nothing is working right

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Just recently I tried adding a new attribute to my CoreData entity, and from what I've read I'm supposed to create a new Model Version of my .xcdatamodeld through Editor>Add Model Version. However, since I did that none of the data I'm trying to save actually saves anymore, furthermore I am told a new .xcdatamodeld file is supposed to be added to my project and that hasn't happened either.

Here is all my code related to me CoreData from saving to loading:

Saving:

```
@IBAction func SaveContact(_ sender: Any) {
        let present = ContactS(context: managedObjectContext)
        if (FN?.text != "" || LN?.text != "" || Email?.text != "" || Phone?.text != "" || Lease?.text != ""){
            present.name = FN?.text
            present.email = Email?.text
            present.coments = Comments?.text
            present.phone = Phone?.text
            let imgData = Picture.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)
            present.image = imgData

            do {
                try self.managedObjectContext.save()
            }catch{
                print("an error has occurred")
            }else{

// this part is not important as it only prompts the user to fill out all text fields
        }
}
```

Loading:

```
    var contact = [ContactS]()
func loadData(){
        let contactRequest:NSFetchRequest<ContactS> = ContactS.fetchRequest()
        do {
            contact = try managedObjectContext.fetch(contactRequest)
            self.TableView.reloadData()
        }catch{
            print("Error!")
        }
    }
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        self.TableView = tableView

        return contact.count
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        self.TableView = tableView

        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        self.TableView = tableView
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! TableClass
        let contacts = contact[indexPath.row]
        cell.Name.text = contacts.name
        cell.Picture.image = UIImage(data: contacts.image!, scale: 1)
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated but delete all lines `self.TableView = tableView` and add an `IBOutlet`

Comment: @vadian what would that do? if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I can answer your question for @vadian, Tariq.  You are grabbing that table view whenever it is passed to a delegate method.  This is quite novel – bringing your table view in "through the back door", I would say.  But novel approaches are usually bad.  Even if they work, other developers looking at your code must spend time scratching their heads.  vadian is suggesting that you instead use the conventional approach and bring your table view in "through the front door".  Now, as vadian said, this is *unrelated* to your migration issue and will not fix it.  It is just some friendly advice.

Comment: When you create a new model version, you do not get a new `.xcdatamodeld`, as you said you were *told*.  What actually happens is that, in your project's source code, you get a new `.xcdatamodel` *package* *within* the `.xcdatamodeld` *package*.  (Note the *d* on the end.)  You can see this in the Xcode Project Navigator.  That package should now have a disclosure triangle.  Click the disclosure triangle to reveal two `.xcdatamodel` packages inside.  Also, if you *Show in Finder* from the contextual menu, you can see the two constituents if you *Show Package Contents*.

Comment: I think before someone can help you with this, you are going to need to do some more work on it (which may lead you to solve it by yourself), and then if necessary, edit your question to make it more focused.  Saying that *none of the data I'm trying to save actually saves anymore* is too vague.  What are you actually seeing?

Comment: First off @Vadian and Jerry Krinock Thank you for the advice, I'll be using the method you two have taught me from here on out.

Comment: @JerryKrinock Sorry for not being clear enough. So basically, when I created the new .xcdatamodel the app was still loading all the previously saved data (the one's I saved prior to creating a new .xcdatamodel) however it was not loading the newer saved data. Also, I went through the Xcode Project Navigator and there doesn't seem to be a new .xcdatamodel (no d) even as I open the project in Finder the files doesn't seem to be there. It's possible that the data I'm saving truly is being saved, however my project is loading from a different source of data. Does this clear anything up? :)

Comment: so I added a bunch of breakpoints and played around with my project, and I learned the reason none of the newly inputed data was being loaded was because for some reason my project wasn't saving anymore. I fixed this issue and and now it works fine, however I've run into a totally different issue that isn't CoreData related (at least I don't think) I would like to thank you all for helping me :)